# Using databricks workspace in the same configuration as the databricks provider

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm having some trouble getting the azurerm & databricks provider to work together.

With the azurerm provider, setup my workspace

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "ws" {
  name                        = var.workspace_name
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                         = "premium"
  managed_resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}-mng-rg"
  custom_parameters {
    virtual_network_id  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
    public_subnet_name  = var.public_subnet
    private_subnet_name = var.private_subnet
  }
}
```

No matter how I structure this, I can't say seem to get the `azurerm_databricks_workspace.ws.id` to work in the provider statement for databricks in the the same configuration. If it did work, the above workspace would be defined in the same configuration and I'd have a provider statement that looks like this:

```
provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.ws.id
}
```

Error:
[image: databricks auth error]

I have my ARM_* environment variables set to identify as a Service Principal with Contributor on the subscription.

I've tried in the same configuration & in a module and consuming outputs. The only way I can get it to work is by running one configuration for the workspace and a second configuration to consume the workspace.

This is super suboptimal in that I have a fair amount of repeating values across those configurations and it would be ideal just to have one.

Has anyone been able to do this?
Thank you :)

Comment: what error do you get? This approach works for me just fine

Comment: Thinking about your response makes me think I've stated something incorrectly. I'll start generating some errors. Probably PEBKAC ;)

Comment: It’s also easier to open an issue in repository itself. It’s better monitored

Answer (score 4):

I've had the exact same issue with a not working databricks provider because I was working with modules. I separated the databricks infra (Azure) with databricks application (databricks provider).

In my databricks module I added the following code at the top, otherwise it would use my azure setup:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databrickslabs/databricks"
      version = "0.3.1"
    }
  }
}
```

In my normal provider setup I have the following settings for databricks:

```
provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = module.databricks_infra.databricks_workspace_id
  azure_client_id             = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  azure_client_secret         = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  azure_tenant_id             = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
```

And of course I have the azure one. Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: ok, this follows an approach I was using as well. I have the workspace living in a module in one of my experiment branches. The difference between mine and yours is your databricks provider setup. I was just setting the `azure_workspace_resource_id`, but I'm not even sure that I knew you could do this with the ARM* variables! Thank you! I'll give it a try and if it works, you can have the answer :)

Comment: @JoshRobinson Did it work? If you need any more code/help, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you experience technical difficulties with rolling out resources in this example, please make sure that [environment variables](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#environment-variables) don't [conflict with other](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#empty-provider-block) provider block attributes. When in doubt, please run `TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply` to enable [debug mode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html) through the [`TF_LOG`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/environment-variables.html#tf_log) environment variable. Look specifically for `Explicit and implicit attributes` lines, that should indicate authentication attributes used. The other common reason for technical difficulties might be related to missing `alias` attribute in `provider "databricks" {}` blocks or `provider` attribute in `resource "databricks_..." {}` blocks. Please make sure to read [`alias`: Multiple Provider Configurations](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) documentation article.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like `Authentication is not configured for provider` could you please configure it through the one of following options mentioned above.

For more details, refer [Databricks provider - Authentication](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#authentication).

For passing the `custom_parameters`, you may checkout the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040451/azure-databricks-workspace-using-terraform) thread which addressing the similar issue.

In case if you need more help on this issue, I would suggest to open an issue here:  https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues

Comment: I have all of my ARM_* environment variables set. I don't actually have to do what Sam is doing to get something working. Usually setting the variables and adding the host to the provider config does the trick. This is what I expect "AZ authentication" means in the error message. However, the error message isn't specific enough.